# How to determine the vertical units for a point cloud in PDAL

Tags: pdal, cloth-simulation

I am creating a PDAL pipeline using Python and the cloth filter (filters.csf). The resolution parameter needs to be specified in the units of the LAS file's coordinate system. I have some point clouds that use meters and some that use US feet. Is there a way using PDAL that I can determine the units?